# Algorithms for computing inverse of $\phi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I am looking for algorithms that compute the inverse of Euler's totient function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/696/) is a nice article off of wolfram that gives an efficient algorithm for computing the inverse of the Euler totient function.

-Download the **invphi.nb** file at the bottom

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I failed to install MathReader on my Linux box. Any references mentioned in the notebook? I'm aware of H. Gupta's 1981 seminal paper but it's not so much of an algorithmic formulation.

Comment: @Mike Singh: No references (but a fairly detailed description of how the program works).

Comment: Oh thanks. I will try to read it on Mathematica on a lab computer or so.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm can be found in the article [Gupta H., Euler’s totient function and its inverse, Indian J. pure
appl. Math., 12(1): 22-29(1981).](https://insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20005a81_22.pdf)